# Is there any Trick to compute the Adjoint of a $3 \times 3$ Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inner-products

I want to know if there exists somekind of trick to calculate the Adjoint of a $3 \times 3$ Matrix, just like we calculate the Adjoint of a $2 \times 2$ Matrix

Comment: Are you asking for the adjugate matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Answer (score 1):

It is an easy exercise to check that the adjoint of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is the conjugate transpose. That is, if $A$ has entries $A_{kj}$, then $A^*$ has entries $\overline{A_{jk}}$.

This is very easy to check:
$$
(A^*)_{kj}=\langle A^*e_j,e_k\rangle=\langle e_j,Ae_k\rangle
=\overline{\langle Ae_k,e_j\rangle}=\overline{A_{jk}}.
$$

Comment: @MathLover: **Adjugate** $\ne$ **Adjoint**.

Comment: I have seen some books where the adjugate matrix is referred to as **classical adjoint** or **adjoint** for short.

Comment: I know, I've seen that, and actually we used the same term for both meanings when I was an undergraduate a million years ago. We'll see if the OP shows up to clarify the intended meaning.